# delete file and error cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, io

I used this code to delete an image. The first time it worked correctly, but the second time I get this error:

```
the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~" + Request["src"])))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~" + Request["src"]));
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~" + Request["src"].Replace("Product\\","Product\\ProductThumbImg\\")));
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~" + Request["src"].Replace("Product\\", "Product\\ProductPreview\\")));
}
```

Comment: Could it be someone is trying to download the image while you are trying to delete it?

Comment: @Kris Vandermotten no, i test it in local

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, you should try the following before your File.Delete(...) code line. It should look this way:

```
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~" + Request["src"]));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find which process is using the file and close it, otherwise you will be unable to delete the image. If you are having problems identifying which process is using the image, try Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).